# inconsistent any vs all pd dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, any

This was asked in other forums but with focus on nan.

I have a simple dataframe:

```
 y=[[1,2,3,4,1],[1,2,0,4,5]]
 df = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

I am having difficulties understanding how any and all work. According to the pandas documentation 'any' returns "...whether any element is True over requested axis".

If I use:

```
~(df == 0)
Out[77]: 
    0     1      2     3     4
0  True  True   True  True  True
1  True  True  False  True  True


~(df == 0).any(1)
Out[78]: 
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

From my understanding the second command means: Return 'True' if any element is True over requested axis, and it should return True, True for both rows (since both contain at least one true value) but instead I get True, False. Why is that?

Comment: See [**De Morgan's laws**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: oh yeah, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python interprets your call as:

```
~ ( (df == 0).any(1) )
```

So it **evaluates `any` first. Now if we take a look at `df == 0`, we see:

```
>>> df == 0
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False
```

So this means that in the first row, there is no such `True`, in the second one there is, so:

```
>>> (df == 0).any(1)
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Now we negate this with `~`, so `False` becomes `True` and vice versa:

```
>>> ~ (df == 0).any(1)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

In case we **first negate**, we see:

```
>>> (~ (df == 0)).any(1)
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Both are `True`, since in both rows there is at least one column that is `True`.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!!

Comment: Thank you both, Willem and jezrael, great explanations!!

Answer (score 3):

You need one `()` because priority of operators:

```
print (df == 0)
       0      1      2      3      4
0  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False   True  False  False

print (~(df == 0))
      0     1      2     3     4
0  True  True   True  True  True
1  True  True  False  True  True

print ((~(df == 0)).any(1))
0    True
1    True
dtype: bool
```

Because:

```
print ((df == 0).any(1))
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool

print (~(df == 0).any(1))
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for the quick answer.